# Populating a pandas DataFrame using column and index labels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have set up an empty pandas DataFrame with numeric column and index labels:

```
cols = np.array([30, 40, 50])
x = np.linspace(0.1,0.6,6)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=x)
```

Given a function,

```
def func(x, b, alpha=5): 
    return x**2 + b*alpha
```

how do I populate `df`? I tried

```
df.update(func(x, cols[:,None]))
```

But it returned nothing and left `df` containing `NaN`s. I know I can loop over the columns, but in NumPy this would be possible with broadcasting and I would like to do the same thing in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
def func(df):
    alpha = 5 
    for col in df.columns:
        for ind in df.index:
            df.at[ind, col] = col**2 + ind*alpha
func(df)
```

**Output**

```
         30       40    50
0.1     900.5   1600.5  2500.5
0.2     901     1601    2501
0.3     901.5   1601.5  2501.5
0.4     902     1602    2502
0.5     902.5   1602.5  2502.5
0.6     903     1603    2503
```

Comment: Absolutely I could look over the columns. I was hoping there'd be a way to broadcast it using NumPy array syntax

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop over it.

```
for index in df.index:
    for columns in df.columns:
        df.loc[index, columns]= func(index, columns)
```

I can't comment on the answers yet but the second answer works as well. The only problem with it is that he switched columns and indexes in the end.
It should be

```
for ind in df.index:
    df.at[ind, col] = ind**2 + col*alpha
```